# What are the 'true events'?

Tags: plot-explanation, check-point

The title sequence of the film [*Check Point*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4519400/) has a part that says "Inspired By True Events".

The story is about a sleeper cell of insurgents who plan to hijack the [USS North Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_North_Carolina_(BB-55)) from its *permanent* mooring in Wilmington and use it to sail to Washington and presumably destroy the capital.  There is a large fire fight between the insurgents and some retired vets, and ultimately the army gets called in and lands ground troops.

I didn't count the casualties, but I'm guessing it was about 30. I can't find anything like this when I search.

What were the **true events** about a domestic insurgency and an attempt to hijack the USS North Carolina?

Comment: "Inspired By True Events" is so broad it can mean just about anything. In this case it is obviously an attempt to present a ridiculous action movie as a "possible scenario".

Comment: *"Inspired by"* is **not** the same as *"Based on"*.

Comment: This reminds me of Fargo, at the start of that movie it says:  "This is a true story. The events depicted in this film took place in Minnesota in 1987. At the request of the survivors, the names have been changed. Out of respect for the dead, the rest has been told exactly as it occurred. "   Later it was revealed the entire movie was fiction and the only true part had to do with the wood chipper.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't based on specific events but on the general state of society. The director and actors have said many times during interviews that the movie is based on the general increase in public fear of terrorist attacks, the building of specific groups of Americans as terrorists against other Americans (AKA hate groups), and the occurrence of actual violence, whether it's terrorist-based or other kinds of violence. In the writer/director's own words (for example, in the YouTube video I'll list below), it's based on a "what if" idea, and the "what if" idea is the part that's inspired by events such as the ones listed above. So far I haven't found any case of Churchill claiming that the events in the movie were actually true, only that the story was a "what if" inspired by real violence, terrorists, hate groups, etc.

As for the USS North Carolina, the ship is still in Wilmington, safe and sound, and you can still tour it. I've emailed them about the story and am watching for their reply. I'll update here when/if they reply to my email.

Most sources repeat the same info, but here are a few examples of sources:

Ron Galletti Interviews Krista Grotte and Thomas Churchhill of Checkpoint

Movie ‘Check Point’ brings fighting to Battleship North Carolina
https://www.starnewsonline.com/article/NC/20150716/News/605044405/WM

Bill Goldberg Starring in "Check Point" a Movie Unmasking Real Life Terrorist "Sleeper Cells" in the USA.
https://www.newswire.com/news/bill-goldberg-starring-in-check-point-a-movie-unmasking-real-life-11934732